# Passing values by reference

Tags: c++

I understand what passing arguments by reference means. A reference is a construct that allows a user to declare a new name for an object. Moreover, it allows to return multiple values from a function passing the variables in by reference.

For example:

```
int i = 7;

int& r=i;
r=9;
i=10;
return r;
return i;
```

However, I didn`t get it to match with my function:

```
int Search(int depth, board b)
{
  board b = combined();
  int w = 0;
   w = Evaluate(b);
  int score;
  int bestScore = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); 
  bool bestMove = false;
  if(depth == 0) return w;
  int x=0, int y=0;
  for (int x = 0; x < 9; ++y) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 9; ++y) {
          while (!occupied(x,y));
          make_move(x, y);              
          score = -Search(depth-1,b);       // recursion 
          unMake(b);
          if(score > bestScore) {         
              bestScore = score;
              bestMove = (x,y);
          }
      }
  }
  return  bestScore; 
  return  bestMove;
}
```

I must surely be missing something unless I can write

```
int & score = bestScore;

int& (x,y) = bestMove;

return bestScore;
return bestMove;
```

Hope someone can help with this.

Comment: if you're doing `bestMove = (x,y);` then the round brackets don't mean, in C/C++, what you seem to think they mean.  `int a = (x, y);` means "evaluate `x` (for its side effects), but then discard its value and assign the value of `y` to `a`"

Comment: Just a side note: your function will never return `bestMove`, and `while (!occupied(x,y));` seems to be going to run endlessly.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that references allowed you to return multiple values, it does nothing of the kind. Rather, it gives you an alternate route for passing values out of a function *in parallel with* the return value.

Comment: 2 `return` one after the other won't return 2 values... Your compiler is certainly telling you that the second `return` will never be reached.

Answer (score 7):

> it allows to return multiple values from a function passing the
>   variables in by reference.

No. A function always returns only one value. You can pass arguments by reference and modify them within the function (unless it's a constant reference), this will modify their values. Consider this example:

```
void Foo (int x)
{
    ++x;
}

void Bar (int &x)
{
    ++x;
}

int x = 0;

Foo (x);
// x is still 0
Bar (x);
// x is now 1
```

If you want to return multiple objects from a function, use `std::tuple` (as Richard Hodges proposed below) or define a `struct`. The former is simpler, but it's relatively easy to mix up the elements of a tuple. The latter has a bit more overhead, but you have clear member names.

As for your case, you need something like

```
std::tuple <int, bool> Search(int depth, board b)
{
  int bestScore = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); 
  bool bestMove = false;

  // do stuff

  return  std::make_tuple (bestScore, bestMove);
}
```

or

```
struct Best
{
  int Score;
  bool Move;
};

Best Search(int depth, board b)
{
  Best best = { std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), false };

  // do stuff with best.Score and best.Move

  return best;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to return multiple values from a function, the conventional and safe way is to use a std::tuple.

It looks like your function wants to return a best score and a best co-ordinate so start with a declaration that looks like this:

```
// holds an x/y coordinate
struct XY {
 // need to declare stuff here
};

std::tuple<int, XY> Search(...args....)
{
   // perform calculations here
   ...

   // return the best move
   return std::make_tuple(bestScore, bestXY);
}
```

Comment: You might also talk about [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

Comment: one baby step at a time... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.Thanks. Something like this:

```
struct XY {
int score;  
XY;
}

tuple<int, XY> Search(int depth, board b)
{
  board b = combined();
  int w = 0;
  w = Evaluate(b);
  int bestScore = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); 
  bool bestMove = false;
  if(depth == 0) return w;
  int x=0, int y=0;
  for (int x = 0; x < 9; ++x) {
  for (int y = 0; y < 9; ++y) {
    while (!occupied(x,y));
     make_move(x, y);              
    score = -Search(depth-1,b);       // recursion 
    unMake(b);
    if(score > bestScore) {         
      bestScore = score;
      bestMove = (x,y);
    }
   }
  }

   // return the best move
   return make_tuple(bestScore, bestXY);
}
```

There must be still some bugs but at least got something together.

Comment: The struct won't compile. What I meant is that you could use *either* tuple *or* struct; there is no need to use them both.

Comment: I added sample solutions to my answer.